# How to embed loops in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function created which outputs only specific numbers based on two input numbers, I'm trying to build a loop that will let me run that function until I get 5 numbers which are all different from each other and add them to a list.

I put what I have so far:

```
list = []
input1=0
input2=5
while len(list)<6:
    newentry =specialfunction(input1,input2)
    if not new entry == list[i]:
        input1 = input1+5
        input2 = input2+5
    elif list.append(newentry):
return list
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible approach using sets:

```
input1 = 0
input2 = 5
entries = set()
while len(entries) < 5:
    newentry = specialfunction(input1, input2)
    entries.add(newentry)
    input1 += 5
    input2 += 5
return list(entries)
```

Here's the trick: `newentry` is added to `entries` only if does not exist yet.